# Does "hearting" farm animals do anything?

Tags: stardew-valley

The first time each day you right-click on farm animals you get a heart, like with your pet. Does this have any effect?

Particularly related to the 5 heart "progress bar" thing you get when you right-click them the next time. Or is that heart "progress bar" just something that grows as long as the animal has food?

Comment: How is this the duplicate when the linked to question was asked *after* mine though? :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, petting (or as you say 'hearting') helps increase the heart progress bar with farm animals.

> Friendship can be raised by daily petting (right-clicking the animal) and feeding.

http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Animals